# Mercurial: keep default branch "active"

Tags: mercurial, branch

I am using mercurial with named branches, and notice that when I create a new branch of default, default is marked as an inactive branch. Eg:

```
C:\data\solutions\test-repo>hg branches
default                        0:aeec280e6310

C:\data\solutions\test-repo>hg branch feature-branch
marked working directory as branch feature-branch

C:\data\solutions\test-repo>hg com -m "created new branch"

C:\data\solutions\test-repo>hg branches
feature-branch                 1:1cb18d7fa554
default                        0:aeec280e6310 (inactive)
```

This is a problem because our deployment system shows named branches that are active, which can be deployed from.

How can I keep my default branch "active" ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The notion of "active" and "inactive" branches is something we're moving away from in the Mercurial project. The problem is simply that branches can flip back and forth between the two states more or less randomly and at inconvenient times — as you've just seen.

Instead, we're now focussing on "open" vs "closed". This is an explicit notion: to close a branch head, you do

```
$ hg update feature-branch
$ hg commit --close-branch -m "passes all tests, ready for merging"
```

That will add a special changeset that marks the branch head as closed. When all heads on a branch are closed, the branch itself it considered closed and will disappear from `hg branches`. I recommend closing *before* merging, please [see my named branch guide for a longer example](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/).

So I suggest you change your deployment system to show open branches (`hg branches`) instead of active branches (`hg branches --active`).

Comment: But how does this keep the default active? As I see it, you HAVE to update to the default after making a named branch, and make a "dummy" commit, otherwise the default branch will be marked as inactive.

Comment: @mslot: I proposed to use closed/open instead of active/inactive. Forget everything about inactive branches and focus on closed branches instead. To re-open a branch you need to make a commit after the changeset that marks it closed — this is normally not a problem since you want to re-open a branch because you have some real change to commit on that branch.

Comment: For your guide a +1, as it is very helpful and descriptive.

Answer (score 15):

Inactive only means it has not a head.

In your case the graph is like this:

```
default:        0 -\
feature-branch:     \- 1 --- *
```

`*` means the "working dir

When you do more fixes in your feature (like nodes 2 and 3) this will be the aspect:

```
default:        0 -\
feature-branch:     \- 1 --- 2 --- 3 ---- *
```

When you want to integrate `feature-branch` into the `default` just update to the `default`

```
default:        0 -\--------------------- *
feature-branch:     \- 1 --- 2 --- 3
```

and then merge `feature-branch` into the `default`:

```
default:        0 -\-------------------/- *
feature-branch:     \- 1 --- 2 --- 3 -/
```

The fact that it appears "inactive" is not meaning you can't work with it. For example, your "deployment scripts" can have a `hg update --clean default` that will perfectly work even if it appeared as "inactive".

Inactive just meant it had no heads. Nothing else. After merging it will become active and it will be `feature-branch` which will become "inactive".

Don't mind its active/inactive state, just work with it normally.

Comment: While this is a good example of showing when a branch is considered inactive, to say 'without a head' is mislead as there *is* a head. In this case the head of feature-branch is 3: `hg heads feature-branch` will confirm this. Rather, it's a business rule (*different* from 'without a head') by which `hg branches` determines in [in]active status.

Comment: The rules is like this: when *all* the children of *all* the heads of a named branch belong to a *different* named branch (as after a merge as shown) then it is considered inactive. Creating a new head on the same named branch (such as adding a commit on the name branch) would instantly violate the rule and it would become, at least momentarily, active again.