# hg update -C <branch> not working as expected

Tags: mercurial, branch, switch-statement

So I've verified from several sources that hg `update -C <branch>` is the approved way to switch branches in Mercurial. However, it doesn't seem to be doing the job for me:

```
Firefly:templatedoc Ken$ hg branches
IntCursor                      7:1aec742eb390
default                        6:bf3fba585a57 (inactive)
Firefly:templatedoc Ken$ hg update -C default
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
Firefly:templatedoc Ken$ hg branches
IntCursor                      7:1aec742eb390
default                        6:bf3fba585a57 (inactive)
```

Thank You!
Ken

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is the problem ? There's nothing "wrong" in your commands and their results... BTW the `-C` option is not necessary and means `clean`

Comment: If your problem is the `inactive` information, you should read this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735032/mercurial-keep-default-branch-active and update your Mercurial version.

Comment: Yes, that was the confusion. thank you. You must admit, it is somewhat confusing--it certainly doesn't map to the concept of "active" that I think most of us understand by default.

Comment: Get in the habit of using 'hg summary' to answer the "what is my current state" question -- that's not 'hg branches''s job, whereas `hg summary` answer's "what's going on and what do I do next" in almost all cases.